# How can I extract pixels values from a large raster in R?

Tags: r, extract, pixel, raster

I'm tring to extract pixels values from raster by intersct with SPDF (`SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`), but gives an error:

```
 library(rgeos)
 library(raster)
```

## I have to do the same with some other rasters and SPDF similar to those in the summaries below:

```
 My SPDF:
 rings<-readOGR("SPDF.shp")

  sumarry(SPDF)
  Object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
 Coordinates:
    min        max
 x -73.99045 -44.241589
 y -18.04159   5.271841
 Is projected: FALSE 
 proj4string : [ +proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs]
 Data attributes:

      Hectares                       
  Min.   :     52    
  1st Qu.:  31110                              
  Median : 141736                              
  Mean   : 442267                              
  3rd Qu.: 531011                              
  Max.   :4203563


 My raster data :
 ras_PI<-raster("ras_PI.tif")

 ras_PI
 class      : RasterLayer 
 dimensions : 86662, 111765, 9685778430  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
 resolution : 0.0002689995, 0.0002690002  (x, y)
 extent     : -73.97832, -43.91358, -18.04061, 5.271491  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
 crs        : +proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs 
 source     : C:/Users/kleds/OneDrive/Documentos/mestrado/PRODES_APs/pAP_PI.tif 
 names      : pAP_PI 
 values     : 0, 1  (min, max)
```

## Here begins my code:

```
dirs<-"~/prodes/PRODES_APs"


 work_dirs<-"~/prodes/PRODES_APs"

#Create a for to define the rasters directory, and to be used in the subsequent for

for (m in 1:length(dirs)) {
files<-file.path(dirs[m],list.files(path = dirs[m], pattern = ".tif"))
nomes <- list.files(path = dirs[m], pattern = ".tif")
nomes <- substr(nomes,1,nchar(nomes)-4)


 }


#create a for to call simultaneously raster layer of interest, and each SPDF (initial polygons, rings and control)


#vectors to use in the for 
AP<-c("PI","TI","UN","US")
AW <- c("arc","wood")
km<-c("min","1km_","2km_","3km_","4km_","5km_","6km_","7km_","8km_","9km_",10km_,"10km","20km","30km","40km","50km","60km","70km", "controle")

 #empty Data Frame to save my results
 results<-data.frame()



for (a in 1:(min(length(files), length(AP)))){
 setwd(work_dirs)

 r<-files[a]
 i<- AP[a]
 map<- raster(r)

for(k in AW){

for(j in km){


   # deffine the directory 
  setwd(paste0("~/prodes/buff_",k,"/AP_rings"))
  getwd()


 # Call each SPDF 
  SPDF<- readOGR(".", paste0("ring",k,j, i))

  names(SPDF)[names(rings) == "X__i__"] <- "TIPO"


  # reproject the SPDF  to ALbers 
  rings <- spTransform(rings, CRSobj = "+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 
 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs ")

  #Extract the pixels values 
  ( extrc <- extract(map, SPDF, na.rm=T) )

  #proportion calculation for each class

 (class.prop = lapply(extrc, function(x) 
 {prop.table(table(factor(x,levels=c(0,1))))}))


  p.prop = setNames(
    do.call(
      rbind.data.frame,
      class.prop),
    c("Desmatado","natural"))

  p.prop$ID<-seq_along(p.prop[,1])


  rings$ID<- 1:length(SPDF)


  freq <- merge(SPDF, p.prop) #add to polygons

  frequenc<-as.data.frame(freq)

  View(frequenc)



  results <- rbind(results, frequenc)
  setwd("~/prodes/resultados")
  write.table(results, file="resultados.txt", sep="\t", row.names=F)

}
}
}
```

## Error: In this point from my code above

```
   ( extrc <- extract(ras_PI, rings, na.rm=T) )

    Cannot allocate large size vector 225.4 mb
```

Comment: Try to run gc() then try to run your code again, maybe it will be enough

Comment: Do I have to run just an empty function`gc()`? and run my code?

Answer (score 0):

The message seems pretty clear. You are extracting a lot of data.

So there are either very many rings and/or they are rather large. So you may need to either provide a function argument to `extract` or loop over the rings.

Perhaps you are doing something wrong ---- but there is no for us to tell as you are referring to data that we do not have. `show(rings)` could be helpful

Comment: In fact, I already made the loop and the part I put in the question is just a fragment of my code and rings is a generic name that I put. I have three spatial data sets that I am crossing with the raster data to extract the pixels. One of these data given are the polygons within my study area and the second data set are concentric buffers (from 1 to 10 km, with 1 km in width and from 10 to 70 km with 10 km in width each). my third spatial data sets are the controls, which are areas greater than 10,000 hectares. the first two data sets ran perfectly.

Comment: Since the control is relatively large and covers a larger amount of pixels, this one is having problems with the processing.